# Can I create an ID in mysql to auto increment like 't00000000'?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create auto incremented id's within mysql with 't0000000' before hand, is this possible?

Comment: What does `'t0000000'` in this context mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Like, do you need the `0`s to be incremented when you're past 9 or not?

Comment: I would just like this to be the ID to be incremented instead of it just being '1, 2, 3' I would like the t00000000 then increment to t00000001 on the next user added

Comment: And what after t99999999?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can use a trigger to intercept insertion and add the prefix you want.

For you example, the table goes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1_seq ( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE table1 (id VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30));
```

The trigger could be like this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table1_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1_seq VALUES (NULL);
    SET NEW.id = CONCAT('t', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 3, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And now, when you insert

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (name) VALUES ('Jhon'), ('Mark');
```

And you'll have

```
|      ID | NAME |
------------------
| LHPL001 | Jhon |
| LHPL002 | Mark |
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this within one table or would I need to separate tables?

Comment: Each table should had its own primary key and adding a trigger for each table would make selection & insertion easy. If you want to handle the key on a single and centralized "index table" you will have a lot of join in all your queries.

Comment: Thank you! I've got this implemented :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) only takes sequence numbers.

What you could do though is to add this prefix in your select query using [`LPAD`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp) with a fixed length of 7 and then append the `t`, like this:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('t', LPAD(ID, 7, '0')) FROM ...
```

That would do the following transformation:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+
| ID     | SELECT CONCAT('t', LPAD(ID, 7, '0')) |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
| 0      | t0000000                             |
| 1      | t0000001                             |
| 15     | t0000015                             |
| 197845 | t0197845                             |
+--------+--------------------------------------+
```